# ASP.NET Core Capturing POST data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an Openlayer's map interface where I'm capturing the user's adding new points to the map.  What I want is to take those location data points and save them do a database.  So I have a working function on the .cshtml page that looks like this:

```
map.on('dblclick', function (evt) {

    var coordinate = evt.coordinate;


    var datapoints = new Array();
    var features = source.getFeatures();
    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
        var poi = features[i];
        var datapt = new Object();
        datapt.X = poi.values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[0];
        datapt.Y = poi.values_.geometry.flatCoordinates[1];

        datapoints.push(datapt);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "Draw_Features", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(datapoints));

});
```

This seems to work just fine and is sending back an encoded JSON of all the locations.  In my Controller file, I have the following:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Draw_Features()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Draw_Features(string someValue)
    {
        //TODO
        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddPointsToDB(string someValue)
    {
        //TODO
        return View("Index");
    }
```

I have two problems:

1) I want to return the data to the "AddPointsToDB()" function but it is instead going to the "Draw_Features()" one instead.  How do I specify in the xhr.send() the correct landing function?

2) I was expecting the function to receive the JSON via the 'string someValue' variable.  But that variable comes in NULL.  What is the correct way to access that JSON from within the function?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Fixed the JSON convert code which was bombing.  Still the same questions...

**EDIT 2:** Showing POST data from Chrome

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u33r.png]

Comment: 1) Your Javascript code explicitly calls `Draw_Features`. If you wanted to call a different action, use *that* action's name. 2) MVC/Web API uses data binding to bind action parameters to body contents and query parameters. There's no `someValue` query parameter in your code. You could specify a specific type and have ASP.NET Core deserialize the JSON string to that type directly, eg `Cooordinate[] coordinates` where the type is `class Coordinate { public double X{get;set;} public double Y{get;set;}`

Comment: You are trying to understand ASP.NET Core going backwards - create a JSON request and try to find out how to make that work. All tutorials work the *other* way though - they show how you can create controllers and actions, how routing works,  how to specify parameters and how to bind them to the query string, body or headers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

# 1)  Ahh...yes, so simple
# 2) OK...made the coordinate class, but a bit lost on where you do the deserialization of it?  In the Controller's header?  Could you give me a small code snippet?

Comment: the framework itself deserializes the payload. All those things are covered in tutorials. For example [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) takes just 16 minutes to read and shows every step needed to create a CRUD-style API, update the database, call POST/PUT etc from Postman and jQuery

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work; the `coordinate` variable is still null.  Still not understanding where the data comes in:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddPointsToDB(CheckInWeb.Models.Geo.cCoordinate[] coordinates)
        {
            //TODO
            return View("Index");
        }
```

Comment: The `Create` action's signature is just `// POST: api/Todo
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)`. By convention the `TodoController` handels `Todo` and the body of a POST is deserialized using JSON.NET to the parameter

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll take a look.  Appreciate the pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a working demo, follow steps below:

1. Define a new model to receive the data instead of string input. For passing `datapoints` to controller action, it will be serialize and de-serialize by MVC Built-in function.

   ```
   public class Coordinate
   {
       public double X { get; set; }
       public double Y { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Change Action with `[FromBody]IList<Coordinate> coordinates` which will specify the modele binding to read the model from body.

   ```
   public IActionResult AddPointsToDB([FromBody]IList<Coordinate> coordinates)
   {
       //TODO
       return View("Index");
   }
   ```
3. As already point out, make sure you set the `xhr.open("POST", "AddPointsToDB", true);` with the action name you want.